# Load Styles in WebPack

Tags: less, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

Is there a way to try to load ***xx.less*** for every ***xx.js*** being loaded?

For now, we add `require 'xx.less'` at the top of every relevant js file and it a little ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended doing was improving the [imports loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader) to add an option to import a `less` file for every `jsx` file with the same name if it exists.

My improved `import loader`: https://github.com/welldone-software/imports-loader

The pull request: https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader/pull/12

For example dropping `mainview.less` in the same directory as `mainview.jsx`,  would add a `require("mainview.less")` import to the top of the `jsx` file:

```
loaders: [
    { test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['imports?null=[./{name}.less]', 'react-hot', 'babel'] },
    { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less' }
]
```